# PostgreSQL very slow on filtering by index

Tags: postgresql

I have `Log` table with `60M` records in it and trying to perform test queries on UserId field with the index. Unfortunately, it's extremely slow, takes about **13 seconds** to scan. I am hosting the database on DO with 8GB RAM, 4 CPU and SSD.

The table structure

```
create table "Log"
(
    "Id"                    integer generated by default as identity
        constraint "PK_Log"
            primary key,
    "Result"                boolean   not null,
    "DateStamp"             timestamp not null,
    "ConversionTime"        integer   not null,
    "ConversionCost"        integer   not null,
    "Converter"             text,
    "SourceFileFormat"      text,
    "DestinationFileFormat" text,
    "Agent"                 text,
    "AgentVersion"          text,
    "Os"                    text,
    "OsVersion"             text,
    "Ip"                    text,
    "Source"                text,
    "Error"                 text,
    "UserId"                integer   not null
        constraint "FK_Log_User_UserId"
            references "User"
            on delete cascade,
    "TokenId"               text
);

alter table "Log"
    owner to doadmin;

create index "IX_Log_ConversionCost"
    on "Log" ("ConversionCost");

create index "IX_Log_DateStamp"
    on "Log" ("DateStamp");

create index "IX_Log_Result"
    on "Log" ("Result");

create index "IX_Log_UserId"
    on "Log" ("UserId");

create index "IX_Log_UserId-all"
    on "Log" ("UserId", "DateStamp", "Result", "ConversionCost");
```

The actual test SQL query which takes more time than should be

```
set random_page_cost=1;
set seq_page_cost=4;

EXPLAIN (buffers, analyse )
SELECT
    "UserId"
FROM "Log"
WHERE "UserId" = 7841

GROUP BY 1;
```

Execution plan

```
Group  (cost=1000.57..1917660.13 rows=626 width=4) (actual time=2.404..13845.150 rows=1 loops=1)
  Group Key: "UserId"
  Buffers: shared hit=6038 read=857126
  ->  Gather  (cost=1000.57..1917657.00 rows=1252 width=4) (actual time=2.389..13895.478 rows=3 loops=1)
        Workers Planned: 2
        Workers Launched: 2
        Buffers: shared hit=6038 read=857126
        ->  Group  (cost=0.56..1916531.80 rows=626 width=4) (actual time=1.134..13841.871 rows=1 loops=3)
              Group Key: "UserId"
              Buffers: shared hit=6038 read=857126
              ->  Parallel Index Only Scan using "IX_Log_UserId" on "Log"  (cost=0.56..1913347.27 rows=1273813 width=4) (actual time=1.132..13721.591 rows=1064916 loops=3)
                    Index Cond: ("UserId" = 7841)
                    Heap Fetches: 3194749
                    Buffers: shared hit=6038 read=857126
Planning Time: 0.097 ms
Execution Time: 13895.539 ms
```

https://explain.depesz.com/s/t8OTa

This is with explain timing

```
set random_page_cost=1;
set seq_page_cost=1;

explain (analyze, buffers, timing)
SELECT
    "UserId"
FROM "Log"
WHERE "UserId" = 7841

GROUP BY 1;

Group  (cost=33076.49..1327372.02 rows=626 width=4) (actual time=769.610..14062.469 rows=1 loops=1)
  Group Key: "UserId"
  Buffers: shared hit=3541 read=853584
  ->  Gather  (cost=33076.49..1327368.89 rows=1252 width=4) (actual time=769.167..14139.210 rows=3 loops=1)
        Workers Planned: 2
        Workers Launched: 2
        Buffers: shared hit=3541 read=853584
        ->  Group  (cost=32076.49..1326243.69 rows=626 width=4) (actual time=759.835..14043.414 rows=1 loops=3)
              Group Key: "UserId"
              Buffers: shared hit=3541 read=853584
              ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on "Log"  (cost=32076.49..1323059.16 rows=1273813 width=4) (actual time=759.611..13614.695 rows=1064916 loops=3)
                    Recheck Cond: ("UserId" = 7841)
                    Heap Blocks: exact=284018
                    Buffers: shared hit=3541 read=853584
                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on "IX_Log_UserId"  (cost=0.00..31312.20 rows=3057152 width=0) (actual time=454.977..454.977 rows=3194749 loops=1)
                          Index Cond: ("UserId" = 7841)
                          Buffers: shared hit=3541 read=5192
Planning Time: 0.140 ms
Execution Time: 14141.648 ms
```

https://explain.depesz.com/s/xEtn

Another "real" query with the same slow result

```
set random_page_cost=1;
set seq_page_cost=1;

explain (analyze, buffers, timing)
SELECT
    "Result"
FROM "Log"
WHERE "UserId" = 7841

GROUP BY 1;
```

Execution plan

```
Group  (cost=1595170.54..1595171.02 rows=2 width=1) (actual time=29233.895..29233.899 rows=2 loops=1)
  Group Key: "Result"
  Buffers: shared hit=72330 read=362500
  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=1595170.54..1595171.01 rows=4 width=1) (actual time=29233.894..29286.971 rows=6 loops=1)
        Workers Planned: 2
        Workers Launched: 2
        Buffers: shared hit=199587 read=1075489
        ->  Sort  (cost=1594170.52..1594170.53 rows=2 width=1) (actual time=29227.651..29227.651 rows=2 loops=3)
              Sort Key: "Result"
              Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
              Worker 0:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
              Worker 1:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
              Buffers: shared hit=199587 read=1075489
              ->  Partial HashAggregate  (cost=1594170.49..1594170.51 rows=2 width=1) (actual time=29227.616..29227.617 rows=2 loops=3)
                    Group Key: "Result"
                    Buffers: shared hit=199571 read=1075489
                    ->  Parallel Seq Scan on "Log"  (cost=0.00..1590985.96 rows=1273813 width=1) (actual time=0.220..28997.691 rows=1064916 loops=3)
                          Filter: ("UserId" = 7841)
                          Rows Removed by Filter: 19154346
                          Buffers: shared hit=199571 read=1075489
Planning Time: 3.910 ms
Execution Time: 29287.100 ms
```

https://explain.depesz.com/s/tjoK

Comment: Why `set seq_page_cost=4`? Making that more expensive than a random access makes no sense. You should at least set both values to the same value. Reading 863164 blocks 1064916 rows from a single column index seems too high. Does running `vacuum full` on that table change anything?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name seeting seq_page_cost to 1 and making both values the same cut time form 13 to 10. Still too long. Vacuum full don't make any improvements.

Comment: Can you please add the new plan? Maybe enable `track_io_timing` and then run `explain (analyze, buffers, timing)`?

Comment: The query itself doesn't really make sense to me to begin with. If you want find out if that userid exists using `select exists (select * from log where userid = 7841)` is probably a lot faster

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name This query is just for testing index scan which works slow. We use a little different query.

Comment: Then show us the real query. As it stands it's really not a valid test (because the EXISTS solution would be a lot faster)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have added explain with timing.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have added real query and actually even slower because it use the same scan UseId index and another Result field to group.

Comment: VACUUM FULL (or any VACUUM) should have changed *something*, unless you have a long-open transaction which is preventing VACUUM from doing its job effectively.  Can you show the first query EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) after the VACUUM?